# I have installed phoneGap lib but am unable to run the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

I have installed phonegaplib for ios, I created one test project using phoneGap based on application template, but in that,  phoneGap.framework is in the red color.  I think it is missing.  So where can I get this frame work, can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're following the official guide?

Create a PhoneGap project (Xcode 4)

- Launch Xcode, then under the File
  menu, select "New Project...".
- Navigate to the "iOS" section, under
  "Applications" - then in the right
  pane, select "PhoneGap-based
  Application"
- Select the "Next" button, name your
  project and company idenfifier, then
  select the "Next" button again.
- Choose the location where you want
  the new project to be.
- Run the    project at least once to
  create the    "www" folder in your
  project folder.
- Drag and drop this "www" folder into
  your project in Xcode, and add it as
  a folder reference.
- Modify the contents of the "www"
  directory to add your HTML, CSS and
  Javascript.

Reference 1: [PhoneGap iPhone - Build and install the Installer Package](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/blob/master/README.md)

Reference 2: [Video: PhoneGap Installer - Xcode 4 Template [HD]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9zktJUN7AI)

Comment: ofcource i followed the above steps but in users/shared folder phoneGap folder is not there y its so

Comment: I understand your issue, trust me the best option you have got is to uninstall it and start over, sometimes we miss single step can produce bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using XCode 4, which is not fully compatible with PhoneGap's default settings.  Use this link to have PhoneGap generate a compatible project for you:

https://build.phonegap.com/generate

Comment: Have you seen the new installer with the Xcode 4 Template? :)

Comment: when did that become available?